# SSH Tunnel "channel x: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out"

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling, sshd

I've Googled and searched far and wide for some sort of "solution" to this problem; however, the best answer I got is "There's nothing that can be done."
Of course, that's unsatisfying, so here goes:

I've set up an SSH daemon back at home and I want to SSH tunnel off of it. SSH works without issues. The tunnel doesn't seem to have issues, either. The command executed locally is...

```
~$ ssh root@xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa -p 53256 -D11323
```

The stuff at home has a router that port-forwards port 53256 to my ssh server at port 22. Everything connects fine, and the tunnel ostensibly works.
On the machine, I put a SOCKS proxy for 127.0.0.1:11323, and I can access sites fine.
However, when accessing particular websites such as ubuntuforums.org or fedoraforums.org, the connection hangs considerably. Then, the shell that has the ssh command spits out the error in the title, and the connection just fails. 
After reading into it, the closest answer I got was there's an issue with "server load or improper configuration." 
However, it baffles me that there's absolutely nothing I can do to connect to those websites through my tunnel.
With all that said, could anyone perhaps provide a solution?

EDIT: This is the output with SSH's -vv option enabled up to the failure:

```
debug1: Connection to port 11323 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 11 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 11 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 5: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 3
debug2: channel 5: decode socks5
debug2: channel 5: socks5 auth done
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: need more
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 5: pre_dynamic: have 23
debug2: channel 5: decode socks5
debug2: channel 5: socks5 post auth
debug2: channel 5: dynamic request: socks5 host ubuntuforums.com port 80 command 1
debug1: Connection to port 11323 forwarding to socks port 0 requested.
debug2: fd 12 setting TCP_NODELAY
debug2: fd 12 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: channel 6: new [dynamic-tcpip]
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 3
debug2: channel 6: decode socks5
debug2: channel 6: socks5 auth done
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: need more
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 0
debug2: channel 6: pre_dynamic: have 23
debug2: channel 6: decode socks5
debug2: channel 6: socks5 post auth
debug2: channel 6: dynamic request: socks5 host ubuntuforums.com port 80 command 1
channel 5: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug2: channel 5: zombie
debug2: channel 5: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 5: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 11323 for ubuntuforums.com port 80, connect from ::1 port 56088 to ::1 port 11323, nchannels 7
channel 6: open failed: connect failed: Connection timed out
debug2: channel 6: zombie
debug2: channel 6: garbage collecting
debug1: channel 6: free: direct-tcpip: listening port 11323 for   ubuntuforums.com port 80, connect from ::1 port 56090 to ::1 port 11323, nchannels 6
```

Comment: minimal reproducer would be useful. Also running the server/client or both in the debug mode to collect some logs before the "failure".

Comment: I have some debug logs from running ssh with -vv, but it's a giant block of text. What's the reccommended way to share it?

Comment: Only the related before failure should be enough to put into the question.

Answer (score 2):

I'm an idiot.
I had some wacky iptables rules set up on my server. After clearing all those out, everything works fine.
Sorry for the fuss.

Comment: Thanks, I actually had the same issue!